# Atualização com modelo HABTM - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, habtm

Estou com problemas para inserir ou alterar dados usando o modelo HABTM, ele não reconhece 3 campos, mas está reconhecendo campos ocultos normalmente.

Segue os arquivos com programação, são 3 tabelas, uma com os dados dos clientes, outros com os dados das opções escolhidas (`usuario`, `senha`, `id_opcao`, etc) e uma outra com qual opção que é (Painel de controle, banco de dados, etc)

**cliente.php - model**

```
public  $hasAndBelongsToMany  =  array (
    'opcoes_clientes'  =>  array (
        'className'  =>  'opcoes' ,
    )
);
```

**ClientesController.php**

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Cliente->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Cliente->saveAssociated($this->request->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash('O cliente foi editado com sucesso!', 
                'alert', array( 'plugin' => 'BoostCake', 'class' => 'alert-success' ));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('O cliente não foi editado. Tente novamente.', 'alert', array(
                'plugin' => 'BoostCake', 'class' => 'alert-error'
            ));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Cliente->read();
        $this->set('clientes', $this->Cliente->read());
    }
```

**editar.ctp** (resumido)

```
echo $this->Form->create("Cliente");
echo $this->Form->input('nome', $options);
echo $this->Form->input('email', $options);
echo $this->Form->input('telefone', $options);
echo $this->Form->input('mais', $options);
foreach($opcoes as $data):
    echo $this->Form->hidden('opcoes_clientes.opco_id', array('value'=> $id));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('opcoes_clientes.cliente_id', array('value'=> $clientes['Cliente']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('opcoes_clientes.host', $options);
    echo $this->Form->input('opcoes_clientes.user', $options);
    echo $this->Form->input('opcoes_clientes.password', $options);
endforeach;
echo $this->Form->end($options);
```

Todos os dados do cliente são alterados normalmente, mas no `opcoes_cliente` apenas insere (caso não tenha) o `opco_id` e `cliente_id`. Os campos `host`, `user` e `password` ficam vazios, mesmo se algum valor for preenchido.

Comment: Ele insere o dado vazio ou não insere??? E ja tentou alterar só para `$this->Form->end();`

Comment: Ele insere com o opco_id e cliente_id com os id's certos, mas o host, user e password ficam vazios, se eu deletar do banco de dados estes registros e salvar o formulário, insere novamente. Sobre o form end é que cortei um pedaço para resumir, mas ali fica a classe do botão e a Label nada que interfira no funcionamento

Comment: Você está carregando o model relacionado no seu *controler*??

Comment: Sim, normalmente, tanto que para puxar os dados funciona tranquilamente, acho estranho porque a inserção ocorre normalmente, mas apenas para dois campos, os outros três não recebe o valor e está dessa forma, nome do input errado não deve ser... será que teria que passar algum outro parametro a mais? Outro detalhe que não acrescentei, no appmodel dei sobrecarga no método saveAssociated de acordo com http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/ccadere/2013/04/19/save_habtm_data_in_a_single_simple_format com isso ele identificou a chave estrangeira

Comment: Tenta usar o layout padrão do cake, e posta aquela query na sua pergunta

Comment: o layout padrão, a view? bem, não sei se poderia interferir, pois não vejo algo que fuja muito de um visual meio padrão, o máximo que uso é bootstrap com menu e tal... enfim, não sei se tem algum método diferente para salvar quando é utilizado o modelo HABTM

Comment: É, não estou entendendo porque não faz a gravação dos outros dados, usei o debugkit e os valores são enviados normalmente junto com o cliente_id e opco_id, o único problema está em salvar

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema

No meu model (cliente.php) deixei com o unique = true

```
public  $hasAndBelongsToMany  =  array (
    'opcoes_clientes'  =>  array (
        'className'  =>  'opcoes',
        'unique' => true,
        'foreignKey'             => 'cliente_id',
        'associationForeignKey'  => 'opco_id'

    )
);
```

A única coisa que ele está deletando e inserindo novamente, parece que o modelo tradicional trabalha assim.

O meu editar.ctp passei as duas chaves

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('opcoes_clientes.'.$i.'.opco_id', array('value' => $id));
echo $this->Form->hidden('opcoes_clientes.'.$i.'.cliente_id', array('value' => $clientes['Cliente']['id']));
```

E todos os campos tem a variavel $i que é um auto incremento para que possa salvar corrretamente

No ClienteController.php, na parte que salva

```
$this->Cliente->saveAssociated($this->request->data)
```